# Adding extra field in filebeat

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

```
filebeat.inputs:

# Each - is an input. Most options can be set at the input level, so
# you can use different inputs for various configurations.
# Below are the input specific configurations.

- type: log

# Change to true to enable this input configuration.
enabled: true

# Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
paths:
   - {some path}
fields:
   target_index: import-export-logger
   build_version: $build_version
```

Here I want to add **build_version** in the fields. My build_version is stored in a file on each server.

Can filebeat read the file and add build_version in the field?

Comment: Hello Gajendar,  were you able to get filebeat to read in the value of build_version from your external file?  I'm trying to do something similar with no luck so far.  Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to add `additional fields` you can add the following lines to your filebeat.yml

```
processors:
- add_fields:
    target: ''
    fields:
      field_name: field_value
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/add-fields.html

If you need to parse the logs and add a dynamic field according to you data, you need to ingest and get the information from logs.

```
processors:
  - dissect:
      tokenizer: "%{key1} %{key2}"
      field: "message"
      target_prefix: ""
```

The above processors will parse the `message` field and will create **key1**,**key2** fields

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/dissect.html

Note: **Dissect** in `filebeat` is like a **grok** in `logstash`.

Comment: My filebeat version is 6.5. Is the above solution compatible with this version

Comment: Look like yes
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/6.5/dissect.html